# Can I use fermented milk product as starter culture?

Tags: fermentation

Can I use fermented milk product as starter culture for vegetable fermenting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Whey, primarily a byproduct of cheese-making (but also from yogurt, kefir &c), can be used to inoculate a variety of ferments. In the book [The Art of Fermentation](https://books.google.com/books?id=-zmLa205d0QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+art+of+fermentation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAGoVChMIo7js9_-ZyAIVhR0eCh2dTAoz#v=onepage&q=the%20art%20of%20fermentation&f=false), for example, there are instructions for using it as a starter for fermenting fruit, vegetable, seed/nut and sour tonic beverage ferments. The most important thing is that the whey not have been heated (most likely in cheese-making) to a point high enough to kill the bacteria present.

My experience is limited (I usually drink my whey or put it in a soup), but I'd imagine you wouldn't want to use anything milkier than whey to ferment veggies with. Fermented milk itself can be used to propagate a mother-culture (e.g. with sour cream, buttermilk, yogurt &c.) but I'm guessing you wouldn't really want to dump these into vegetables.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, but it depends what you are trying to achieve with your vegetable fermenting as to whether you *should.*

*i.e.*, my survey of the lore of sauerkraut yielded *a few* suggestions to do that sort of thing, but they were definite outliers, as were the suggestions to use old sauerkraut liquid to "start" new sauerkraut, or *obviously paid/pandering* advice to buy starter cultures of some sort.

By far the most widely accepted view was that sauerkraut needed **nothing of the sort,** simply cabbage and salt and a lack of air, with the bacteria already present on the leaves doing just fine, thank you, without any "help" beyond the right amount of salt (generally accepted as 2-2.5% by weight of the cabbage) and a clean place to work, preferably without oxygen.